# Why can't I update my Drupal modules and themes?

Tags: updating, maintenance-mode

Suddenly I found my self in a big issue: I just can't upadate my Drupal modules and themes.

When I run the update script via the GUI, the download phase passes correctley (or it seems to be). But when I perform the database update and I click to "Continue" and putting the site under maintennace mode, nothing happens. And also a major problem come: the maintenance mode persist even when I disable it.

To resolve that issue I clear all the cache from the database.

Any idea or help for that?

Answer (score 1):

1) try to run the updates via drush

2)are you sure that the new module version has a new hook_update_N in it? If not then there will be nothing happening during the update in GUI

Comment: I can't use drush i hosted the site with limited access..

Comment: and i don't know how to verify that the new modue has a new hook_updateN in it

Comment: Then are you sure that there is a database update in the install file of the module?

Comment: You can check the system table in the database and look what number is there: for example 7011. If you have a yourmodule_update_7012 or higher then there is a database update. If not then there is no database update and only code reafactoring and bug fixes.